# how to diference the same string if this was written or scanned (bar code)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, barcode

I am programming on C#, for Handhelds, well problem is next
when a client is visited user for look for it, he keys the client's number.
but now it is going to be scanned, 
for example with client 123
normally i go and i write 123 for look for this client and now i press "sale" for start a sale.(it is with a button cuz a client has plus option for example questionary for ask it questions)

now this same number would be scanned and in that moment, automatically it must to open the sale.

is there a event when a bar code is read?
or how can i to difference if this was scanned or keyed
my real question how to know if a string as scanned?

> windows mobile framework 3.5

Comment: You need to supply more information. Is this WPF? WinForms? A different framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to look at the DLLs that come with the scanner. My company just did a similar project in Mobile Framework 3.5 with a barcode scanner. We have our own proprietary DLL that exposes an OnSuccessfulScanHandler event and tie that into the SuccessfulScan even from the Scanner object.

I would imagine that those events would be part of any other software package as well.

In the SuccessfulScan event, you can have it automatically fill the Textbox and proceed through to process the data automatically, and also set up a boolean for whatever object to determine if it was scanned or entered manually.